# Does the existence of partial derivatives imply Frechet differentiability?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ and $a \in \mathbb R^n$such that $\forall i \in [1,n], \large \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a)$ exists.

Is $f$ Frechet differentiable ?

I'd say no, but I don't know any counter-examples...

Comment: The answer becomes positive if the partial derivatives exist and are continuous functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $n = 2$, and $m = 1$, and consider

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} &, (x,y) \neq (0,0)\\ \quad 0 &,(x,y) = (0,0).\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ isn't even *continuous* at $(0,0)$, but the partial derivatives exist. (The partial derivatives exist on all of $\mathbb{R}^2$. $f$ is Fréchet-differentiable everywhere except at $(0,0)$.)